# MySQL Selecting Certain Variables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm fairly new to MySQL and I'm currently trying to display only the data that has the variable "activities" equal to multiple entries: murals, concert, theater, and museums. How would I do this?

`SELECT * FROM trail101 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 9`

Comment: `WHERE activities IN('murals', 'concert', 'theater', 'museums')`

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/where.php is what you're looking for

Comment: Or the long way `WHERE activities = 'murals' OR activities = 'concert' OR activities = 'theater' OR activities = 'museums')`

Comment: Am I the only one who reads this as `activities` is a (poorly-designed) comma-separated column and the OP wants to find rows where this column contains multiple values?

Comment: @Nicole Could you please provide your DB schema, some sample rows, sample input, and what you would want the sample output to be?

Comment: you have to use where clause you can read about it [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/where.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `WHERE` clause.  The long way:

```
SELECT * FROM trail101 WHERE
    activities = 'murals' OR
    activities = 'concert' OR
    activities = 'theater' OR
    activities = 'museums'
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 9
```

Or with `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM trail101
    WHERE activities IN('murals', 'concert', 'theater', 'museums')
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 9
```